# How to get the second to last value in a list?

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I have a list which contains multimple lists inside it and it looks like this:

```
my_list = [
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', '0,012'], 
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', '0,153'], 
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', '0,114'],
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', '0,109'],
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', '0,252'],
    ['Spain', 'Fish', '0,012'], 
    ['Spain', 'Fish', '0,113'], 
    ['Spain', 'Fish', '0,116'],
    ['Spain', 'Fish', '0,250'],
    ['Spain', 'Fish', '0,266'],
    ['Italy', 'Fish', '0,112'], 
    ['Italy', 'Fish', '0,025'], 
    ['Italy', 'Fish', '0,224'],
    ['Italy', 'Fish', '0,256'],
    ['Italy', 'Fish', '0,245']]
```

And I have a variable which looks like this:

```
my_limit = 0.2
```

Now for every list I want to get the last value before it exceeds `my_limit`. I want that value to be stored in a new variable.

This is what I tried:

```
for l in my_list:
    if row[-1]  #<-- this is actually where I block.... I dont know how to fix it.
```

This is the output I expect:

```
0,109
0,116
0,025
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6633912/4518341) for how to do locale-aware number conversion.

Comment: @wjandrea that answer is confusing me. I dont need to converse any numbers....or converse a string with a float.....

Comment: @TangerCity You do need as the numbers in your array have a comma `'0,012'`.

Comment: Yes you do... You need to get values like `'0,012'` into floats, and the builtin won't do it: `float('0,012')` -> `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0,012'`

Comment: Oke but converting them to floats is just halve of the problem is it?

Comment: @Tanger Yes, exactly, that's why I left a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: What result do you expect for a sequence like `"0,110", "0,256", "0,196"` with a limit of `0.2`? Just to double-check whether you want a position-based result or a value-based one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module for this

```
>>> import itertools
>>> my_list = [
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', '0,012'],
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', '0,153'],
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', '0,114'],
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', '0,109'],
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', '0,252'],
    ['Spain', 'Fish', '0,012'],
    ['Spain', 'Fish', '0,113'],
    ['Spain', 'Fish', '0,116'],
    ['Spain', 'Fish', '0,250'],
    ['Spain', 'Fish', '0,266'],
    ['Italy', 'Fish', '0,112'],
    ['Italy', 'Fish', '0,025'],
    ['Italy', 'Fish', '0,224'],
    ['Italy', 'Fish', '0,256'],
    ['Italy', 'Fish', '0,245']]
>>> my_limit = 0.2
>>> for key,sublists in itertools.groupby(my_list,lambda y:y[0]):
        v=[] #we initialize it in case no element fulfill the condition
        for v in itertools.takewhile(lambda x:float(x[-1].replace(",","."))<my_limit ,sublists):
            pass
        if v: 
            print(v,"->",v[-1])

    
['Morocco', 'Fish', '0,109'] -> 0,109
['Spain', 'Fish', '0,116'] -> 0,116
['Italy', 'Fish', '0,025'] -> 0,025
>>>
```

here with [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) we, well, group together all the consecutive sublist that have the same value in a given position we specify, which in this case is the first position, then we go into those sublist and take those that fulfill our condition and stop at the first that doesn't with [takewhile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) and from those we only want the last one which will stored into `v` at the end of the loop.

I make that grouping because that make more sense to my, but if grouping like that isn't necessary, we can also use groupby to split the list into the subsection that fulfill the condition and those that do not by changing the grouping key

```
>>> my_list = [
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', '0,012'],
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', '0,153'],
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', '0,114'],
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', '0,109'],
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', '0,252'],
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', '0,002'],#extra
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', '0,252'],#extra
    ['Spain', 'Fish', '0,012'],
    ['Spain', 'Fish', '0,113'],
    ['Spain', 'Fish', '0,116'],
    ['Spain', 'Fish', '0,250'],
    ['Spain', 'Fish', '0,266'],
    ['Spain', 'Fish', '0,066'], #extra
    ['Spain', 'Fish', '0,366'], #extra
    ['Italy', 'Fish', '0,112'],
    ['Italy', 'Fish', '0,025'],
    ['Italy', 'Fish', '0,224'],
    ['Italy', 'Fish', '0,256'],
    ['Italy', 'Fish', '0,245'],
    ['Italy', 'Fish', '0,005'],#extra
    ['Italy', 'Fish', '0,305']]#extra
>>> for condition,sublist in itertools.groupby(my_list,lambda x:float(x[-1].replace(",","."))<my_limit):
        if condition:
            for v in sublist:
                pass
            print(v,"->",v[-1])

        
['Morocco', 'Fish', '0,109'] -> 0,109
['Morocco', 'Fish', '0,002'] -> 0,002
['Spain', 'Fish', '0,116'] -> 0,116
['Spain', 'Fish', '0,066'] -> 0,066
['Italy', 'Fish', '0,025'] -> 0,025
['Italy', 'Fish', '0,005'] -> 0,005
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's simply a matter of iterating over the list and reporting `list[n-1]` when `list[n]>my_limit`.

You will need to extend this to cope with edge cases (i.e. this will error if the first value is over the limit etc.)

And you might want to split your list into one list per commodity as this will trigger when commodities change too.

```
my_limit = 0.2

for n in range(1, len(my_list)):
    value = float(my_list[n][2].replace(",", "."))
    prev_value = float(my_list[n-1][2].replace(",", "."))

    if value > my_limit and prev_value < my_limit:
        print(my_list[n-1])
```

Comment: @what does the `[2]` mean in your 3rd row?

Comment: That's the position of the price within your sub-list.

Comment: try `print(my_list[1])` and `print(my_list[1][2])` and you'll see.

Comment: Ahh your code is neat men. Great, thank you. If you could just add some comments in it. I dont understand what you did at prev_value for example...

Comment: One more thing, I get the whole list as a result instead of just the numbers who are before `my_limist`.. How is that?

Comment: If you just change it to `range(1, len(my_list))`, you avoid the error with the first value.