# How do I turn a string with a comma and a dot to a float?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have a problem with turning a string into a float value. I'm screaming a website and trying to get the prices in to float values, but the problem is that the prices can look like this:

$2,549.98

$2,262.64

$999.00

```
marketprice = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/app/content-holder/marketplace-detail/landfield-detail/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/span')
userprice = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/app/content-holder/marketplace-detail/landfield-detail/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[6]/span')
print(marketprice.text, userprice.text)
imarketprice = float(marketprice.text[1:])
iuserprice = float(userprice.text[1:])
```

When I try to convert the error I get:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2,549.98'

Is the problem with it that there are a comma and a dot?

Comment: You could just remove the commas. FYI normally not a good idea to represent monetary amounts as floats.

Comment: yes that is the problem

Comment: @Chris not really. Because a *lot* of text files use thousand separators. You need to use the proper parsing method, not just use `float()`

Comment: Proposing to remove thousand separators is a hack. There are **good duplicates** [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779288/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number-if-it-has-commas-in-it-as-thousands-separato)

Comment: Use `locale.atof` instead. Replacing won't work in half of the world, where `,` is the *decimal* separator. If you try replacing commas in Europe, Russia, Africa or South America you'll end up removing the decimal separator

Comment: The currently accepted answer in the duplicate is NOT the right way to do this. Use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6633912/2386774) instead. Money should always be represented as Decimal, not float.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the commas using:

```py
imarketprice = float(marketprice.text[1:].replace(",", ""))
```

Comment: That's a hack that only works for very specific locales, esp. US and China. It won't work in half of the world. `locale.atof` can handle any locale