# How to get float numbers formatted with dot and comma

Tags: python, pandas

I need all numbers in my pandas dataframes converted to german number notation. It means there should be thousands decimal dot and a comma for fractions.

example.:

```
52.634,99
```

I can do it easily the other way around, first comma, then dot:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.2f}'.format
```

Why is it not possible to use it this way?

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.,2f}'.format
```

error:

```
ValueError: Format specifier missing precision
```

Comment: A hacky way would be to use the method that works, then replace commas by dots and viceversa using `string.replace()`

Comment: Does Pandas use the current locale to format values?

Comment: Your attempt doesn't work because the order of things in the field format is strictly defined; it's not just a set of characters.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633523/how-can-i-convert-a-string-with-dot-and-comma-into-a-float-in-python .

Answer (score 1):

> converted to german number notation

This is task for [`locale`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html) built-in module, you can use it following way:

```
import locale
import pandas as pd
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'de_DE')
pd.options.display.float_format = lambda x:locale.format_string('%.2f',x,True)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[5663499e-2]})
print(df)
```

output

```
          x
0 56.634,99
```

Explanation: use german (de_DE) numeric convention, `'%.2f'` is 2 digits after `,`, `x` is value itself, `True` is use thousands sep. For futher discussion see [`locale.format_string`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.format_string) in docs.

Comment: I tried your code but without `df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[5663499e-2]})`it doesn't effect my dataframes.

Comment: @stanvooz are your dataframes holding `float`s or just `str`s with some representation of float?

Comment: they are holding floats

Comment: @Stanvooz this is surprising for me, what version of `pandas` are you using?

Comment: I have version 1.1.3 installed

Comment: @stanvooz what happens if you run my code exactly as-is?

Comment: It prints: `56634,99`

Comment: @stanvooz then I do not know what might be reason for your `pandas.DataFrame` not working as intended