# Regex that matches only numbers in a percentage separated by comma or dot

Tags: python, regex, validation

I use python, for example, I have a string like this:
`a good 98.15% play` it should match 9815,
`a good 98,15% play` it should also match 9815,
`a good 100% play` it should match 100
`a good 98% play` it should match 98

I have tried to use `(?<=\s)\S+(?=\%)` to match the whole 98.15 but there are more people using comma to separate decimal number than I thought and I tried to use other regex but there aren't any I could think of that satisfy my problem.

Comment: Why are you not looking for digits?  `\d\d*([.,]\d*)?%` should do it.

Comment: @shellawa – What do you want returned from `a bad 10.0% play`?

Comment: @Armali I have found the solution. But before, the regex I use would return "10.0" and then I convert it to a number, it would be different from 100%

Comment: If you have found the solution, then provide it as an answer or delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution, I can just use string replace method to replace all commas with dots, and then use my old regex `(?<=\s)\S+(?=\%)`, it should match the number of that percentage (98.15 as in 98.15%)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `.` if it is there, and the regex to capture the numbers. I'd remove the . first, then simply `(\d+)%`

In python, I think its .replace('.','') to remove the `.`

Comment: But in that case, how can I know if it’s 98% or 9.8%? I don’t think everyone would write 98.00%

Comment: Oh, I can just replace comma with dot and use my old way, thanks for pointing out

Comment: Check out string padding: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/add-padding-to-a-string-in-python/

You should be aware of float conversion `float("23.23")` (and locale issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633523/how-can-i-convert-a-string-with-dot-and-comma-into-a-float-in-python)

Also consider someone doing something greater than 100%, could they use both comma and `.`? e.g. `5,000.95%`?

Comment: locale is such an issue, it's good that a "play" never exceeds 100% tho. thanks for the information

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
\d+(?:[,.]?\d+)?%
```