# Is there a simple and preferred way of German number string formatting in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, localization, locale, string-formatting

I am searching for the proper way of German number formatting (e.g. `1.000,1234`) in Python under Windows OS.

I tried `locale.setlocale` but did not succeed.

Instead, I have written a function to come up with the desired output.

Is there a better way?

```
def ger_num(number, precision=3):
    """
    returns german formatted number as string or an empty string
    """
    if number is not None:
        try:
            my_number = "{:,f}".format(number)
        except ValueError:
            return ""

        decimals, fraction = my_number.split(".")[0], my_number.split(".")[1]
        decimals = decimals.replace(",", ".")

        if precision:
            return decimals + "," + fraction[:precision]
        else:
            return decimals

    else:
        return ""
```

Comment: please provide a clear description of your inputs and outputs.

Comment: What exactly have you tried with `locale`? Perhaps your platform doesn't support it? See the many answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287051/german-number-separators-using-format-language-on-osx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `locale.setlocale` to set the locale to `de` and then use `locale.format` to format your number:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de')
print(locale.format('%.4f', 1000.1234, 1))
```

This outputs:

```
1.000,1234
```

Comment: On Debian you might want to check your specific locale identifiers by running `locale -a` and if it's missing check out `man locale-gen`.
I'm using `de_DE.utf8`. Also, `locale.format` is deprecated in Python 3.7. Use `locale.format_string()` instead.

Answer (score 4):

If for some reason `locale` does not work for you (or is not desired), then the easiest other option would probably be to use string replacement, like suggested in [this already mentioned answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14287227/9225671) (which draws its answer from the [PEP-378](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0378/#main-proposal-from-nick-coghlan-originally-called-proposal-i)).

You can always encapsulate that in a function, maybe like this:

```
def format_number(number, precision=3):
    # build format string
    format_str = '{{:,.{}f}}'.format(precision)

    # make number string
    number_str = format_str.format(number)

    # replace chars
    return number_str.replace(',', 'X').replace('.', ',').replace('X', '.')
```

This works well for `int`, `float` and `Decimal`:

```
>>> format_number(1)
'1,000'
>>> format_number(1, 2)
'1,00'
>>> format_number(1, 7)
'1,0000000'
>>> format_number(1234567, 7)
'1.234.567,0000000'

>>> format_number(1234567.9988, 7)
'1.234.567,9988000'
>>> format_number(1234567.9988, 2)
'1.234.568,00'

>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> format_number(Decimal('1234567.9988'), 2)
'1.234.568,00'
>>> format_number(Decimal('1234567.9988'), 5)
'1.234.567,99880'
>>> format_number(Decimal('1234567.9988'), 0)
'1.234.568'
>>> format_number(Decimal('123456'), 5)
'123.456,00000'
```

Comment: I was able to edit this func into something that allowed me to display euro symbol in front of euro formatted currency - much neater than worrying about locale

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. If anyone finds this useful I do provide the code for my final solution here.

ger_num.py:

```
def ger_num(number, digits=2):
    '''
    retruns <number> as german formattet string (thousands-.),
    rounds to n <digits>.

    <number> == None OR (!= INT AND != FLOAT) returns '' (empty STR)
    '''
    import locale
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de')
    if number is None:
        return ''
    if not isinstance(number, int) and not isinstance(number, float):
        return ''
    else:
        format = '%.'+str(digits)+'f'
        return locale.format_string(format, number, 1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

If `locale` has an for you issue again, I would propose simple string replacement. The proposed `format_number` function above is great, but it does not always preserve the input. For instance,
`format_number(Decimal('1234567.9988'), 0)` does transform English to German format, but it removes the numbers after the decimal point.
A simple safe way to just tranform any English string number to a German string number is this:

```
de_number = number.replace(".", "$DECIMAL$")
de_number = de_number.replace(",", ".")
de_number = de_number.replace("$DECIMAL$", ",")
```

From the post I gathered that the input number is always positive, but in case it can be negative, you could use `number[1:]`instead of `number`. If the majority of the input numbers are negative, it might worth using `locale`, which seems to deal with them by default.

To format an input German string number into an English string number without altering the input again, use:

```
en_number = number.replace(",", "$DECIMAL$")
en_number = en_number.replace(".", ",")
en_number = en_number.replace("$DECIMAL$", ".")
```

If `en_number` does not have thousand separators but only decimal points, it can now be properly used in Python like in `float(en_number)`. For instance, `float("5000.0")` works, but the German equivalent `float("5000,0")` would give a `ValueError`.