# How to extract YYYYMMDD date from the "Tue Aug 06 20:13:58 CEST 2013" in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, locale

I have a SQLite3 database where date and time is stored as a string like `"Tue Aug 06 20:13:58 CEST 2013"`, and I need to extract some of the data into a CSV file.

I know how to open the database, connection, and cursor (reading), and how to open the output CSV file for writing (using the `csv` module).

The datetime string should be converted to the `"YYYYMMDD"` string -- i.e. `"20130806"` in the above case.

My idea was to use the `datetime.datetime.strptime("Tue Aug 06 20:13:58 CEST 2013"
, frm)` to get the `datetime` object that would be later used for producing the formatted vallue. However, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 18, in <module>
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, frm)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\_strptime.py", line 500, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\_strptime.py", line 337, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'Tue Aug 06 20:13:51 CEST 2013' does not match format
'%a %b %m %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'
```

I thought it can be problem with the locale, as I am using...

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.getdefaultlocale()
('cs_CZ', 'cp1250')
```

However, I am not able to set the locale to `'en'`, `en_us`, or the like:

```
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python33\lib\locale.py", line 541, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
```

I need your eyes and experience.

Comment: Well, a naive approach would be to simply split the string on `" "`, extract month, date, year, map the month name to a number and concatenate the result...

Comment: @l4mpi: +1 I can do that, and I will probably do that. Anyway, I would like to solve the above problem anyway.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547631/python-locale-error-unsupported-locale-setting) seems to answer the `locale` part - there's no locale with this name. As the locale determines the names used for days/months I think it explains the `strptime` error too. [Another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/955986/what-is-the-correct-way-to-set-pythons-locale) implies Windows uses nonstandard locale names; so you'll need to find the correct name for the english locale. Oh, and you should probably not set `LC_ALL` but `LC_TIME`, which is what `strptime` uses.

Comment: @l4mpi: Well, the locale things seems to be a mess on Windows. Actually, it is a question whether the `datetime` approach is the correct one. I have found several other date formats used in the database that I should process. As I actually want to *fix the formated string* that were produced elsewhere, I cannot be sure I could always determine the correct locale. Please, copy your comment on the "naive approach" as the answer, so that I am able to accept it.

Comment: @l4mpi: Please, copy your comment on the "naive approach" as the answer, so that I can close the question by accepting it. ;)