# Python - How to show a date using strftime in other language?

Tags: python

I have this:

```
from datetime import datetime

    d = datetime.now()
    print d.strftime ("It is %A %d. %B %Y"
```

How to I set a language to give me a date? I want it for example is ES or DE.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/985517/65387 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/956084/65387

Comment: Change `It is` to `El es` for ES, I believe

Comment: If the intro is too complex, you can do a variety of things. You can create a dictionary with languages mapping specific keys (language names) to values (the translations), or you can retrieve the translation of your welcome message with google translate. But the simples is what @Mark suggested to use pythons locale.