# English as language for the dates ticks using matplotlib

Tags: datetime, matplotlib, non-english

I'm a French native speaker, so my OS interface (GNU/Linux Xubuntu) is in French

Thus, when I plot a time series using Matplotlib with `datetime` as X data, the returned plot have the months written in French

How can I obtain those printed dates in another language (typically English) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the desired location/language using the [`locale`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html) module. To get English, try setting `locale` to `en_US`.

**EDIT**:
In bash on Ubuntu, you may need to use `en_US.utf8`

```
In [1]: import datetime 

In [2]: import locale

In [3]: locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'fr_FR')
Out[3]: 'fr_FR'

In [4]: datetime.datetime(2015,7,1).strftime('%B')
Out[4]: 'juillet'

In [5]: locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'en_US')
Out[5]: 'en_US'

In [6]: datetime.datetime(2015,7,1).strftime('%B')
Out[6]: 'July'
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using GNU/Linux (Xubuntu Distribution), and ```locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'fr_FR')``` generates the error ```locale.Error: unsupported locale setting```

Answer (score 4):

Using tom's answer and [the post hereafter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955986/what-is-the-correct-way-to-set-pythons-locale), the local settings for an Ubuntu-like OS are :

`import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'en_US.utf8')`

The list of available languages can be obtained in the terminal with

`$ locale -a`