# Font Crash on Pandas plot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

My DF is consisted by Korean Lang.
I have no idea for fixing it.
How can i solve it?
[image]

Comment: Have a look at this answer and see if it helps:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32974640/english-as-language-for-the-dates-ticks-using-matplotlib

Comment: Does [Display foreign language in matplotlib (in virtual env)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48374379/display-foreign-language-in-matplotlib-in-virtual-env) help you?

Comment: Thank you! i solved via installing something and deleting cache! Hard to solve such a technical problem! @Ynjxsjmh