# How to make pythons datetime object show AM and PM in lowercase?

Tags: python, datetime

Over here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior it says that `%p` displays AM / PM. It shows this

```
AM, PM (en_US);
am, pm (de_DE)
```

I'm not sure what `de_DE` is, but when I do `%p` using Django Rest Framework it shows AM and PM in capital letters. How do I change it so that am and pm are displayed in lowercase?

This is my DRF `settings.py` code where I edit the datetime format (might not be useful):

```
#added REST_FRAMEWORK
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ),
    'DATETIME_FORMAT': "%b %d at %I:%M %p"
}
```

Comment: might want to look at `babel` package for internationalization stuff

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try changing '%p' to '%P'.  Whether '%P' is supported depends on the 'strftime' function provided by the platform C library.

Comment: +1 for recommending an un-documented feature. And for future readers, here's a link to `strftime` for [Perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/TimeDate/lib/Date/Format.pm) and [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php), which specify `%p` and `%P`. And yes, upper/lower case is flipped. (`%p` = AM/PM & `%P` = am/pm)

Comment: And if `%P` is not supported, like on Windows at least, the we get `ValueError: Invalid format string`

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure that you cannot.  The `%p` format code is the locale-specific "national representation of either "ante meridiem" (a.m.)  or "post meridiem" (p.m.)  as appropriate".  `de_DE` is the generic German locale which is what defines the national representation which happens to be lowercase.  The `en_US` locale has it defined in uppercase.  Part of using functions like `strftime` is that they take care of the localization details for you.

The documentation does explicitly mention that the exact values are entirely locale specific:

> Because the format depends on the current locale, care should be taken when making assumptions about the output value. Field orderings will vary (for example, “month/day/year” versus “day/month/year”), and the output may contain Unicode characters encoded using the locale’s default encoding (for example, if the current locale is ja_JP, the default encoding could be any one of eucJP, SJIS, or utf-8; use locale.getlocale() to determine the current locale’s encoding).

Comment: Thanks for the information. Another comment pointed out trying to change `%p` to `%P` and it worked (it is now lowercase).

Comment: I was going to mention that except that it is very platform specific

Answer (score 4):

`en_US` and `de_DE` are [locales](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html).

`en_US` = English US
`de_DE` = German Germany

In the `en_US` locale, AM/PM are uppercase whereas for the `de_DE` locale, it's shown in lower case.

You can use `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')` to [change your locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/956084/1431750) when you use time formatting and then revert it back after.

And to avoid issues with other date fields showing in the wrong order, like 'day,month,year' instead of the US-preferred 'month,day,year', when you use the time formatting options, make sure you specify all the fields and not one of the standard short/long time formats, since those will always be as per the locale. Example, `%x`:

```
%x    Locale’s appropriate date representation.    08/16/88 (None);
                                                   08/16/1988 (en_US);
                                                   16.08.1988 (de_DE)
```

However, doing this is not a good idea, since the month (for example) will appear in that language's name. So 'May' will appear as 'Mei' (affects both long and short forms).

A ***dirty workaround*** is to do a search and replace after the generating the timestring:

```
>>> datetime.strftime(datetime.today(), '%c %p').replace('AM', 'am').replace('PM', 'pm')
'08/10/16 10:37:49 am'
>>> datetime.strftime(datetime.today(), '%c %p').replace(' AM', ' am').replace(' PM', ' pm')
'08/10/16 10:39:19 am'
```

Again, not recommended since that will interfere with the timezone part where 'AM' and 'PM' occur - 'AMT', 'PMDT', 'GAMT'. If you're not displaying that or any other alphabets like for month, then it should be okay.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation you've linked:

> Because the format depends on the current locale, care should be taken
>   when making assumptions about the output value. Field orderings will
>   vary (for example, “month/day/year” versus “day/month/year”), and the
>   output may contain Unicode characters encoded using the locale’s
>   default encoding (for example, if the current locale is js_JP, the
>   default encoding could be any one of eucJP, SJIS, or utf-8; use
>   locale.getlocale() to determine the current locale’s encoding).

So, I don't think you can do it with a simple formatting option without overriding locale settings which may irritate users if you end up overwriting their locale settings.

**Two suggestions:**

- Use another formatting lib like [Django's DateFormat](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/dateformat.py) ('a' will give you lowercase am/pm)
- If you're using Linux that uses glibc then you can use "%P" as Python's strftime() is backended by C-lib's strftime()

Comment: Using `'a'` gives `a.m.` or `p.m.` but not `am` or `pm`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, albeit kinda klunky, is to store only the "AM/PM" portion of the timestamp to another variable, then simply do:

```
my_ampm = now.strftime("%p").lower()
```