# ValueError: Invalid format string

Tags: python, string, time, module, format

what is the problem in this- `string=strftime("%H:%M:%S %P")`
when i run the code it called me

```
string=strftime("%H:%M:%S %P")
ValueError: Invalid format string
```

what is the solution please tell me.

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes, it's valid as long as the C version of his system considers valid: [`strftime(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html). From the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior): "The full set of format codes supported varies across platforms, because Python calls the platform C library’s strftime() function, and platform variations are common. To see the full set of format codes supported on your platform, consult the strftime(3) documentation." So he should call `man 3 strftime` and see if it's available.

Comment: @IainShelvington On my system, Python 3.8.10, GCC 9.4.0, `from time import strftime`, the result of calling with "%P" is lower-case "am", and the result with "%p" is uppercase "AM". As the manual says, it varies according to implementations...

Comment: @EnzoFerber: is there a way to specify a cross-platform date format string?

Answer (score 0):

This works great, although without %p

```
from datetime import datetime
n = datetime.now()      


string=n.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print(string)
```

To understand why it might not work with %p read this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38863256/3847725

Comment: Try testing your code on this online interpreter https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/
And see if your code works, it might be locale specific is what i'm trying to say.