# configure sort order in sublimetext3

Tags: sublimetext3

I know how to sort lines in Sublime (ctrl+p "sort"). The problem is it doesn't sort some characters as I want, namely åäö.

Is there some way to change how sublime orders the text? Perhaps by a specific locale? It would also be interesting to be able to sort V and W as being equal.

Example: I want the following words to be sorted in this order:

```
bår
bär
bör
```

but Sublime sorts it like this:

```
bär
bår
bör
```

Comment: https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1324#issuecomment-240993210

Answer (score 0):

There has been a similar request logged on ST's issue tracker: https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1324

One of the ST developers replied:

> Sorting in Python 3 uses Unicode code points as the basis for sorting. Sublime Text doesn't know what language your encoding represents, so it doesn't use locale-based sorting rules.
>
> This seems like it is probably best solved by a package dedicated to providing locale-based collation rules.

Using https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer, we can see that the `case_sensitive_sort` method in `Packages/Default/sort.py` uses Python's built in `list.sort` method. Typing the following into ST's Python console (View menu -> Show Console), we get the same result as you have shown:

```
>>> a = ['bår', 'bär', 'bör']
>>> a.sort()
>>> a
['bär', 'bår', 'bör']
```

So the answer is that there is no *setting* to configure the sorting behavior, and nor is there likely to be in future. However, according to https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#odd-and-ends, it is possible to use a locale-aware sort using `locale.strxfrm` as a key function.

Let's try. On Windows, I had to use

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_COLLATE, 'sve')
'Swedish_Sweden.1252'
```

to get Python to use a Swedish locale - as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/956084/4473405

```
>>> a.sort(key=locale.strxfrm)
>>> a
['bår', 'bär', 'bör']
```

Using this knowledge, you might choose to change the `case_sensitive_sort` method, so that ST's built in sort functionality (Edit menu -> Sort Lines (Case Sensitive)) will use the locale aware sort key. Note that saving the `sort.py` file opened from PackageResourceViewer will create an override, so that if future builds of ST include changes to `sort.py`, you won't see them until you delete the override (which you can do by finding the file using the Preferences menu -> Browse Packages -> Default. You can reapply your changes afterwards, if appropriate, using the exact same steps.)

You can also change the `case_insensitive_sort` method from

```
txt.sort(key=lambda x: x.lower())
```

to

```
txt.sort(key=lambda x: locale.strxfrm(x.lower()))
```

Note that, if your correct locale isn't picked up automatically (it probably defaults to `C`), [then setting the locale in this (`case_sensitive_sort`) method isn't recommended, even if, immediately afterwards, you restore it back to what it was beforehand - so use at your own risk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#background-details-hints-tips-and-caveats).

> It is generally a bad idea to call `setlocale()` in some library routine, since as a side effect it affects the entire program. Saving and restoring it is almost as bad: it is expensive and affects other threads that happen to run before the settings have been restored.

You could instead add the following to the end of the `sort.py` file:

```
def plugin_loaded():
    import locale
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_COLLATE, '')
```

which will, when the plugin is loaded, allow Python to infer the locale from your `LANG` env var, as per https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.setlocale. The advantage being you only set it once, and hopefully won't introduce any problems with other plugin code executing at the same time.

Happy sorting!