# How to change locale in python in windows?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, locale, setlocale

I want to format price in integer to properly formatted currency. Example 10000 to  or ₹10,000

So, I am using the following commands in python

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_MONETARY, 'en_US')
or
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_MONETARY, 'en_IN')
print str(locale.currency(10000, grouping=True))
```

**When I use the above commands in python in ubuntu in different laptop, they are working perfectly fine. But, on windows they are not working.**

Its giving me error as follows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\locale.py", line 581, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
```

**How to solve this error ?**

I am using Windows 10. I open cmd and type "python" enter. The python shell is presented with following version. There I type the above commands.

```
Python 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 09:01:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
```

**Note :-** I tried copying the locale.py file from python directory in ubuntu system to Windows directory i.e., "C:\Python27\Lib" but its still not working.

Comment: Please follow this:
[locale settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547631/python-locale-error-unsupported-locale-setting)

Comment: @Dharmesh the link you provided gives answers for ubuntu system, and not for windows system. Have you tried any solution ? If yes, then please give the solution. Thank You.

Comment: Also look here: [What is the correct way to set Python's locale on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955986/what-is-the-correct-way-to-set-pythons-locale-on-windows).

Comment: @direprobs I have seen that link. and I can set 'en_US' for $ but I need 'en_IN' for ₹ How can I do that ? Just try it please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at the [pycountry](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycountry) library to have a mapping between Windows and Linux language codes:

```
>>> pycountry.languages.lookup('fr')
Language(alpha_2=u'fr', alpha_3=u'fra', bibliographic=u'fre', name=u'French', scope=u'I', type=u'L')
>>> pycountry.languages.lookup('french')
Language(alpha_2=u'fr', alpha_3=u'fra', bibliographic=u'fre', name=u'French', scope=u'I', type=u'L')
>>> pycountry.languages.lookup('chinese')
Language(alpha_2=u'zh', alpha_3=u'zho', bibliographic=u'chi', name=u'Chinese', scope=u'M', type=u'L')
>>> pycountry.languages.lookup('chinese-traditional')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
LookupError: Could not find a record for 'chinese-traditional'
```

Then you can do:

```
import os
import locale
import pycountry

lang = "en_IN"  # your code
language = pycountry.languages.lookup(lang)
if os.name == "posix":
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_MONETARY, language.alpha_2)
else:
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_MONETARY, language.name)
```

**EDIT**

To format currency values, you may consider using [Babel](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/api/numbers.html), for instance:

```
>>> babel.numbers.format_currency(10000, 'INR', locale='en_IN')
u'\u20b9\xa010,000.00'

>>> print(babel.numbers.format_currency(10000, 'INR', locale='en_IN'))
₹ 10,000.00
```

Comment: its working, but there is one slight issue for which I want to know the reason. I used the above code and used lang = "hindi" then after setlocale in else part, it was success but when I used the following line print str(locale.currency(10000, grouping=True)) it gives me the following output ?10,000.00    I want to know why there is ? instead of ₹    any Idea ? or have I done anything wrong ?

Comment: str() uses 7-bit ASCII (in Python 2.7) for conversion from unicode, your currency symbol is outside of that range, so it gets converted to the replacement char.

Comment: Is there any solution for that ? without str also its question-mark

Comment: @AvtarSingh: You may consider using [Babel](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/api/numbers.html).

Comment: On Windows, the `en-IN` locale is available for Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows 8, Windows Server 2012, Windows 8.1, and Windows Server 2012 R2. Not for Windows 10. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc233982.aspx

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE ohh.....thats the reason behind all this.....then I think we can not do anything regarding this matter.....I'll try once in windows-7 and see what happens and then I will revert back to you......I will also give a shot to Babel.....Thank You

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE I still have not tried on Windows-7 but I just tried Babel on Windows-10 and its nice....but its giving me the following error........
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u20b9' in position 0: ordinal not in range(256).....when I use following command......print format_currency(1099.98, 'INR', locale='en_IN')......for USD and en_US.....its printing $ perfectly......how u printed ₹ ?

Comment: @AvtarSingh: You have this error because your console doesn't support UTF-8 and is configured to use ISO-8859-1 (latin1). So, this is only a problem with `print` on your console, the result is OK.

Comment: "en-IN" is available in the Windows NLS API starting with Vista, and it's certainly available in Windows 10. However, the C runtime that's used by Python 2.7 doesn't understand the new WinAPI locale-name strings that were introduced with Vista, such as "en-IN". It uses LCIDs instead, which are looked up via either the full names or 3-letter abbreviations (e.g. "english_india" or "eng_ind"). Even in Python 3, the CRT version handles locale-name strings, but the locale module itself doesn't, primarily because it wants to use underscore and Windows requires a hyphen.

Comment: The issue with "?" for the currency symbol is because the "en-IN" locale uses 1252 as its legacy codepage, which is meant for Western Europe and doesn't map the "₹" character. The C runtime used by Python 2.7 (VS 2008) doesn't have wide-character alternatives for these fields in the `lconv` struct that C `localeconv` returns. Starting with VS 2010 (used by Python 3.4), MSVC added `wchar_t` alternatives such as `_W_currency_symbol`, so this wart could be addressed in Python 3 if you want to create an issue on the tracker.

Comment: @eryksun thank you very much for the info......directly using the following command without any 3rd party library is working absolutely fine...... locale.setlocale(locale.LC_MONETARY, 'eng_ind')......i.e., using "eng_ind" is working fine......but question mark still remains there instead of ₹....but that you also explained why......thanks for all the info

Answer (score 1):

### For Python 3.6.4 I did the following on Windows 10

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'enn')
>>'English_India.1252'
locale.currency(10000000.32,grouping=True,symbol=True)
>>'? 1,00,00,000.32'
locale.currency(10000000.32,grouping=True,symbol=True).replace('?','₹')
>>'₹ 1,00,00,000.32'
```

Answer (score 0):

For windows, you need to set `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '<language string>')`
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39cwe7zf(vs.71).aspx (deprecated)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39cwe7zf(v=vs.140).aspx (updated).

Comment: You are right for $ i.e., en_US. But how can I set India for (₹) The msdn link does not contain India English language string. I want to use ₹

Comment: I can use 'en_IN' in ubuntu system but I am not able to use it in Windows system. What is 'en_IN' in windows ? Just try it please.