# Python - How to set French locale?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, locale, french

`locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'french')` work on my local machine (windows 7 + Python 3)

`locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'fr_FR.UTF-8')` work on my other machine (Unix) but if I use this on my local machine, I have this error:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'fr_FR.UTF-8')' failed: unsupported locale setting
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to set Python's locale on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955986/what-is-the-correct-way-to-set-pythons-locale-on-windows)

Comment: @Jonathan, no duplicate, `fr_FR.UTF-8` work only on one machien and `french` on other. I have already seen this post before asking my question and it is precisely by doing so that I have the problem.

Comment: Supported locale names depend on the platform and version. For Windows Python 3.5+, which uses the Windows Universal C Runtime (UCRT) library, see [UCRT Locale names, Languages, and Country/Region strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/locale-names-languages-and-country-region-strings?view=vs-2019). Note that [BCP 47](https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47) language tags are preferred, which use hyphen instead of underscore (e.g. "fr-FR"). Python's `locale.getlocale` function doesn't parse these yet.

Comment: The BCP 47 form doesn't allow a ".codepage" suffix, except recently they started allowing ".utf-8" or ".utf8". Windows is Unicode and doesn't conflate language/region locale settings with text encodings.

Comment: The Universal CRT still supports legacy Windows locale names of the form "language[_country[.codepage]]". Note that these use either the [full English name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Intl/locale-senglish-constants) or Microsoft's [non-standard abbreviations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Intl/locale-sabbrev-constants). For example, the abbreviated name for the "French_France" locale is "fre_FRA",  or "fre_FRA.1252" with a codepage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this in RobotFramework (at the beginning):

```
${osName}=    Evaluate    platform.system()    platform
Run keyword if    "${osName}"=='Windows'    Evaluate    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'french')    locale
    ...         ELSE    Evaluate    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'fr_FR.UTF-8')    locale
```

Answer (score 1):

Locale settings are OS dependent and, at least on *nix systems, might even depend on whether they are installed or not.

This SO post might be a good pointer to what locales to use on Windows systems: https://stackoverflow.com/a/956084/2186184

Comment: That's right. I'm using Ubuntu and I needed to install a specific language pack.