# execute localized formatting inside a function under windows

Tags: python

I want to implement inside a function localized formatting so that the typed in value `12,3` is recognized as a float

```
import locale

def localize(argument):
    if argument == "do it":

        locale.setlocale(category=locale.LC_ALL,
                 locale="German")
#         locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'deu_deu')


          x = float(input("type in a float"))

          print(x)

    else:
        pass
```

I tried every commbination from this thread [correct way to set Python's locale on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955986/what-is-the-correct-way-to-set-pythons-locale-on-windows#956084) but so far its not working, Im aware that that the change can be implemented without localized formatting, but I want to do this in this particulare way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change locale only in one specific place, use a context manager and with statement to revert locale after the block. Use [`locale.atof`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/locale.html#locale.atof) function to parse float according to locale and [`{:n}`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) to format according to locale.

```
import locale
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def localized(code):
    old_code, old_encoding = locale.getlocale()
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, code)
    yield
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, f"{old_code}.{old_encoding}")

with localized("pl_PL.utf8"):
    x = locale.atof("3,5")
    print(x) # 3.5
    print(f"{x:n}") # 3,5
    print("{:n}".format(x)) # 3,5
```

Comment: is this working for you ? , I guess you have linux,  I dont know how it can return a float in the first place, when I type in `12,3`  it is going to be a tuple,

Comment: Yeah, I focused mostly on the reversing mechanism. I edited the answer. `locale.atof` did the trick on linux. Let me know if it works on windows

Comment: if I type in `12,3` in the input is the output from  `print(x)` also `12,3` ?

Comment: Not by default, but you can use string formatting to respect locale in formatting numbers. See the edited answer.

Comment: I have found a workaround  using regex but I may need your aproach later