# Is there a way to get the list of locales available to pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, windows, localization, locale

I've been trying to get the name of the month from a datetime series in a language other than English using panda's month_name on Windows.

According to the function's definition, I only need to set the locale parameter to the language code I want but I keep getting 'Error: unsupported locale setting'.

What could be the problem? Is there a way to get the current locales available to pandas?

Comment: you need to update your locale using the locale module `import locale; locale.getlocale();locale.setlocale(args)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash, execute `locale -a` to get locale

```
obj = pd.to_datetime('2021-01-15')
obj.month_name(locale ='en_US.utf8')
```

more info:

- [What is the correct way to set Python's locale on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955986/what-is-the-correct-way-to-set-pythons-locale-on-windows)
- [Python locale error: unsupported locale setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547631/python-locale-error-unsupported-locale-setting)